# Making some fields editable when a particular button is clicked from a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I am trying to write a logic where I have to clone a custom objectwith its child (having lookup relationship). The clone record show appear with status 'New' and Date- Month fields for that record should be editable to the user . Else everything should be read only.

I am able to do the cloing perfectly with the logic written below but stuck with the portion of making the month date field editable only when clone button is clicked and status of the record is 'New'.

Could you please advice the steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with the `setRedirect(true)`.  When you set the PageReference to redirect the view state is wiped out.  This means that the `clone` variable will have its initial value when the page loads.  It doen't retain the value that you set.

I can think of two possibilities for you:

1. Don't use the `setRedirect(true)` so that you don't lose the view state.
2. Continue using `setRedirect(true)`, but create a query to set the `clone` variable to something from a value in the Database, so that it isn't dependent on a variable set before the redirect is done.

I'm not 100% certain of how the `clone` variable is being set, though, so I might not be correct.

Comment: "clone" is just a Boolean variable which is set to true when the user clicks on clone button. It thought it would help me  in making the pageblocksection visible/hidden by this line -- "<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!clone}">". since the date-month field in the page will only become visible to  user when he clicks on "clone" button.Rest of the times I need not to show this date-month field. Hope this helps.

Comment: The clone doesn't make it hidden because of the redirect. Your code sets it to true, but then a redirect is done which clears the context/view state.  If you are staying on the same page after the cloneAction is called then remove the setRedirect(true).  You can just return null. There's some [more explanation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_controller_navigation_methods.htm).

Comment: Peter Knolle, thanks for your i/p.however, can you suggest me what can be done in that case? I need to clone and after cloning happens have to redirect to the new record's page. thnks

Comment: Sure. `return new ApexPages.StandardController(theNewRecAfterInserted).view();`, where `theNewRecAfterInserted` is the new record after you've inserted, so that it has an Id.  That will redirect to the detail page for that record

Comment: thanks. Also, I dont want the end user to use the same month & year in clone date as that of the parent records month-year. How can I check that validation and throw an validation error messgage to user is he tries to insert a cloned record with same month-year combination as that of parent record? Menas, the following lines should not be the case while cloing a record. //ilrClone.PFE_ILR_Month__c= ilr.PFE_ILR_Month__c;
//ilrClone.PFE_ILR_Year__c = ilr.PFE_ILR_Year__c ;
Kindly advice.

Comment: Basically: `if (yourErrorCondition) { ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,’Error Msg'));  return null; }` and in VF in part of page that is rendered: `<apex:pageMessages />`. More on [different messaging options here](http://jessealtman.com/2013/08/difference-between-the-multiple-messaging-options-in-visualforce/)